# A problem related to orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

let  $A$ be a real $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix ,that is ,$A^tA=AA^t=I_n$, which of the following statements are necessarily true?

1. $<Ax,Ay>$= $<x,y>$ $\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^n$
2. A is diagonalizable over  $\mathbb R$.
3. the rows of A form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$

Since $AA^t=I_n$, then (3) is true.what about others.please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) is true because 
\begin{align*}
\langle Ax, Ay\rangle & = \langle x, A^TAy\rangle\\
& = \langle x, I_ny\rangle\\
& = \langle x, y\rangle    
\end{align*}

2). need not be true for example take $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then this is an orthogonal matrix but not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$. However it is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$.